# Convert number to another number in n steps

Tags: python, list, numbers

I want to make a gradient function, and I need the R G and B values to change the same number of times. My current code (python) is this:

```
def a2bn(a:int, b:int, n:int):
    __l = []
    __c = 0
    for i in range(n):
        __c += (b/n)
        __l.append(__c)
    return(__l)
```

However, it doesn't work because it can't have a starting value (A) without messing up the list. (the function takes in single numbers, but I can use three of them to combine the lists).

Comment: Can you please supply expected output?

Comment: If you want there to be a gradient from a to b, shouldn't you initialize `_c=a` and then update by `_c += (b-a)/n`?

Comment: inside the question not as comment

Comment: If I run:
`print(a2bn(0, 15, 3)`
I should get:
`[0, 5, 10, 15]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you want there to be a gradient from a to b, shouldn't you initialize `_c=a` and then update by `_c += (b-a)/n?` – Isdj

This worked, thanks!
(tomorrow this will be marked as answer)